# Factory class that automatically loads subclasses of specific superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, static-libraries, factory

Before I describe my problem let my say that I suspect I might simply lack the correct terms to search for, and that's why my searches here on stackoverflor haven't been fruitful. So links to answers would also be very much appreciated.

Im trying to make a library that has a Factory, lets call it "MyFactory". MyFactory has a method that returns objects of the abstract class "MySuper", but also one that exposes the avilable subclasses to "MySuper". The library is intended to be expanded on a lot, so subclasses of "MySuper" will be added often, and then library will be recompiled, and dumped into a library folder of the application that uses it.

What I want is to be able to add a subclass of "MySuper" to the library, and have "MyFactory" become aware of it, preferebly without having to do anything else than create a new sublass of "MySuper"..

So far I use reflection to make "MyFactory" create new instances of a "MySuper" type, by giving the class name to a method, like this:

```
public MySuper getSuperObject(String name) {
    return (MySuper) Class.forName("my.package." + name).newInstance(); }
```

But how can I get the factory to expose alle the "MySuper" classes as f.x. a List of String, so the applications that use the library know what they can call? Can I iterate the content of a package?

I'm open for solutions, the most important part is that in the future it should be very hassle free to add new "MySuper" sub-classes..

Thanks :-)

UPDATE:

I just want to note that I have found a nice Java library that handles reflection in an easy way, and lets you search for subtypes of a specific class. So my problem can be solved with that library (I have tested it). Here is a link: http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `Generic Factory Pattern`. Something like..

```
public static <T extends MySuper> T createDocument(Class<T> subClazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return subClazz.newInstance();
    };
```

You may google for `Generic Factory Pattern` and you will find lots of examples.

Comment: That looks really good. But how do I go about making the library aware of the sub-classes so that I can expose somthing like a `ArrayList<MySuper> mySubClasses` to the applications using the library? My google searches reveals mostly ways to actually instanciate the sub class (Like how you showed me). I suspect that I need a way to investigate a package in the project, to see if it contains classes that extends MySuper?

Comment: Im not sure if I understood correctly, but You are looking for `Find all the sub-classes for a given class/interface?`. If that is the case I have written a blog long long back. You may find that helpful which returns the `List<SubClass>` for a given class. Hope then you can use reflection to create instances for those classes. Here is the link http://nonstop-rp.blogspot.in/2010/05/java-reflection-know-subclasses-of.html .. As I said this is an old blog..

Comment: That looks very promising and is exactly what I'm looking for. I will accept your answer - and snoop around in your blog.

Answer (score 1):

The default class loader knows nothing about a class until it searches for it. It then looks in several places depending on the class path. If you depend on the class loader you will not be able to get the class into the list until it has already been asked for by name.

The most automatic solution may be to designate a location, such as a directory, for new classes extending MySuper. To construct the list of classes, look in that directory for class files, and use your favorite bytecode library to check them for classes that extend MySuper.

Another option is to have a configuration file that lists the extending class names.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an enum that contains the possible subclasses to MySuper. whenever you add a subclass add an entry in the enum for the same and then you can give that as an input to the getMySuperObject() method.

do comment if u think i have left something in this solution

Comment: Well I do see how that is a valid solution, as it does not require to much knowledge of the system. The thing is that many developers might need to add ne "MySuper" subclasses to the library, and the less they need to know about the system the better. So I was hoping for a solution where they would only need to add the subclass, and then the library would automatically handle the rest.

Comment: if you want to expose an api that will pick any class that is in a particular package or extends another class, then thats tough however you may provide a configuration file which is read on startup and this file contains an entry of the list of classes that you have created. This is how we have done it in our application as of now.